# Trying to understand bond prices

Tags: bonds

I'm trying to learn about bonds, but when I looked at some real-world charts, they don't seem to make much sense to me...

For example, these two bonds:

[image: Comparison between two bonds]

Same company, same rates, same maturity dates, but wildly different prices (and also, very different trade histories).
What would explain this difference, and if I bought them now, what would I actually have to pay?

Comment: Is one of them callable? Can you post the individual ISINs?

Comment: The CUSIPs are [00430HAB8](http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondDetail.jsp?ticker=FAXDX4833965&symbol=AXDX4833965) and [00430HAA0](http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/BondDetail.jsp?ticker=C750115&symbol=AXDX4612993).

I found the filing for [one of them](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/727207/000114420418017533/0001144204-18-017533-index.htm), but I couldn't find the other...

Comment: Did you look at the dates of those charts ?

Answer (score 2):

The trade histories don't overlap, which makes me think that the original bond (00430HAA0) was re-issued under a new CUSIP (00430HAB8). I don't see anything in their financial reports that would explain the change in identifiers, but that bond is the only one that they list as active in their financials.

In any cases, the price for 00430HAA0 is not "current", meaning you couldn't necessarily buy it for that amount - it's just reporting what it was actually traded for on that date.

Comment: Yeah, that makes the most sense, considering the trade histories. It's just weird that all the "Issue Elements" are filled out in the retired one, and empty in the current one...

Comment: Regarding the price — you're saying that, even though the last trade was just a few days ago, the current price might be significantly different? And how would I find it out? Would I have to call my broker?
And, last but not least, assuming the company doesn't go bankrupt, that this look like a good deal? To me, as a newbie, it does, but what do I know... ;)

Comment: I think hes referring to 00430HAA0. If you look at the last trade date it hasn't been traded since 04/01/2019 so the last trade price will naturally be very different from 00430HAB8 which was last traded 06/10/2020, over a year later.